# Wanted but not invoked: Mockito and Powermock

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

I have a Junit test that I inherited that is no longer working. It is using PowerMock 1.4.12, Mockito 1.9.0 and Junit 4.8.2.  It was working awhile back but stopped and I am trying to get it to work again.

```
Wanted but not invoked:
clerkReviewPackageHelper.addSubmissionQueue(
    <any>,
    <any>,
    <any>,
    <any>
);
-> at icis.cr.approvefilingdetail.CRFilingToQueuesActionTest.test_post_handled_add_submission_queue(CRFilingToQueuesActionTest.java:47)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

    at icis.cr.approvefilingdetail.CRFilingToQueuesActionTest.test_post_handled_add_submission_queue(CRFilingToQueuesActionTest.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:66)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:312)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:86)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:94)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:296)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:284)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:209)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:148)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:102)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

**Here is the code for this test:**

```
@Test
public void test_post_handled_add_submission_queue() throws Exception {
    when(request.getMethod()).thenReturn(BaseCRAction.POST);
    when(sessionInfo.getSubmissionId()).thenReturn(SUBMISSION_ID);
    when(crFilingToQueuesForm.getAction()).thenReturn(null);
    crFilingToQueuesAction.executeProcess(actionMapping, crFilingToQueuesForm, request, response);
    verify(clerkReviewPackageHelper, times(0)).removeSubmissionQueue(null);
    **verify(clerkReviewPackageHelper).addSubmissionQueue(any(String.class), any(String.class), any(String.class), any(String.class));**
    verify(actionMapping).findForward(eq(BaseCRAction.FORWARD_SUCCESS_REDIRECT));
}
```

And this is the method that it calls from the line in the exception:

```
public void addSubmissionQueue(String submissionId, String queueId, String reviewOn, String employeeId) throws BadDBConnection {
Session session = injector.inject();
session.executeNonSelectingCall(clerkReviewPackage.addQueue(submissionId, queueId, reviewOn, employeeId));
session.release();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: You are correct Jeff, as I looked through the check in logs you are right.  I need to brush up on mockito and powermock, so I can update these unit tests.

Comment: Glad to help! I deleted the above comment and promoted it to an answer, so you can mark the answer as accepted (or so other contributors can expand and edit). Be sure to ask if you have any specific questions about what the code does, or how to fix particular lines you can paste in. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `executeProcess` *used* to call `addSubmissionQueue` but doesn't anymore, but without the code of `executeProcess` it's hard to say for sure.

If it's appropriate not to call `addSubmissionQueue`, you can simply delete the reference to that verification line. If it is important to call it, or call it under specific circumstances, edit the test so the `verify` line only happens in test cases where a call to that method is required.

Note that because Mockito is involved, your test isn't calling the actual code for `addSubmissionQueue`, but a *mock* instead. Read more about how Mockito works in [the examples on the Mockito homepage](https://github.com/mockito/mockito#how-do-i-drink-it).

Answer (score 0):

**Try :**

```
import org.mockito.Mockito;

// ...

Mockito.verify(clerkReviewPackageHelper, Mockito.times(0)).addSubmissionQueue();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `clerkReviewPackageHelper` mock doesn't seem to be associated with your call to `executeProcess` in any way.  It's not passed in, and it doesn't seem to be returned, directly or indirectly, from any method calls on any mocks that *are* passed in to `executeProcess`.  It therefore hardly seems reasonable to expect one of its methods to get called by `executeProcess`.

What you need to do is look through the call to `executeProcess` and find the object, if any, on which `addSubmissionQueue` is called.  Without seeing the code for `executeProcess`, I can't really offer assistance with this.  It may be but there is no such method call, as @JeffBowman has conjectured in his answer.  But there are also other possibilities.

- If the object on which `addSubmissionQueue` is called is one of the parameters to `executeProcess`, then you should use `clerkReviewPackageHelper` as the corresponding argument in the test.
- If the object on which `addSubmissionQueue` is called is an a field in the one of the parameters to the `executeProcess`, then inject `clerkReviewPackageHelper`, either in the constructor of `crFilingToQueuesAction`, or a setter, or even with `@InjectMocks`.
- If the object on which `addSubmissionQueue` is called is obtained from a method call on one of the other parameters to `executeProcess`, then you need to make that call return `clerkReviewPackageHelper`.  This might mean injecting that value into some object, or it might mean stubbing a method call on a mock.  For example, if the method that you're testing obtains `clerkReviewPackageHelper` by calling a line like `crFilingToQueuesForm.getHelper()`, then you need to write `when(crFilingToQueuesForm.getHelper()).thenReturn(clerkReviewPackageHelper);` or something similar.  It may turn out to be more complex than this of course.  I can't tell without seeing your code.

If you need more help, then please post the code of your `executeProcess` method.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue while writing testcase for my controller method,what i missed is am passing the parameters to my test method those are declared but not initialized inside the setup method, so i did them in setup method and the issue fixed.